# How to continue processing the next row in the processor when it fails in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Suppose that two data were read using HibernateCursorItemReader in spring batch.
Suppose that an Exception occurred while processing the first row data in process.
The job listener is handling the failure.
But here the job ends normally.
I want to continue processing in the processor for the second row, what should I do?

Job

```
@Bean
  public Job sampleJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("sampleJob")
        .start(sampleStep())
        .listener(jobListener)
        .build();
  }
```

Reader

```
@Bean
  @StepScope
  public HibernateCursorItemReader<Sample> sampleItemReader() {
    return new HibernateCursorItemReaderBuilder<Sample>()
        .sessionFactory(entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class))
        .queryString("select ...")
        .fetchSize(100)
        .saveState(false)
        .build();
  }
```

processor

```
@Override
  public Sample process(Sample sample) throws Exception {
    try {
         ...
    }catch (Exception e) {
       throw new MyException();
         //When an exception occurs, the job listener handles it. **When is the next row read from the reader processed?** It just ended...
    }

    return sample  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FaultTolerant skip logic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringSkip) in your sampleStep() bean. Add these below configuration in your sampleStep() bean:

```
.faultTolerant()
.skipLimit(10)
.skip(Exception.class)
// If you want to skip for any specific exception, you can put it above.
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I realized that when an exception occurs, the batch status becomes Failed, and at this time, the batch is no longer executed for the next row.
So, it was modified so that no Exception occurs.